# How to create a dynamic dependent form select options data model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django. I'm trying create an ecommerce application in which the user will select from a category of options [automobile, property, electronics, phones, clothes etc], and upon selecting an option (say automobile), the next select field options will be populated asking for model [Honda, Toyota, Chrysler etc], if user select say Toyota, a list of Toyota models comes up [Camry, Highlander, Corolla, etc.], upon selecting say Camry, another set of options comes up asking for year, and so on.

How do I implement (generate and/or store) this type of data using django models? I'll be very grateful for a swift response to this.

Thank you.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.